# Есть ли в yandex картах рисование произвольного контура и сглаживание контура по нажатию кнопки мышки как в cian.ru?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

В cian.ru на карте города можно нажав кнопку "Нарисовать область" нарисовать на карте произвольный контур, потом сам cian.ru его сглаживает и отображает объекты недвижимости внутри данного контура. Не могу понять, это возможности от yandex карт или разработка самого cian ?

Comment: Редактор геометрий - часть API, сглаживание и поиск внутри области - разработка самого cian над возможностями API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В API Яндекс.Карт есть [редактор полигонов](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygonEditor), но он немного другой.

Если вы хотите поведения как на cian.ru, то проще положить поверх карты `canvas`, рисовать на нем и запоминать координаты, а после из них собрать полигон.

Отфильтровать гео-объекты по попаданию в полигон можно с помощью [`geoQuery(myObjects).searchInside(polygon)`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult-docpage/#searchInside) или [`polygon.contains(coordinates)`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IPolygonGeometryAccess-docpage/#contains).

```js
var polygonOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#0000ff',
  fillColor: '#8080ff',
  interactivityModel: 'default#transparent',
  strokeWidth: 4,
  opacity: 0.7
};

var canvasOptions = {
  strokeStyle: '#0000ff',
  lineWidth: 4,
  opacity: 0.7
};

ymaps.ready(['Map', 'Polygon']).then(function() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', { center: [55.75, 37.62], zoom: 8 });
  var polygon = null;

  var drawButton = document.querySelector('#draw');

  drawButton.onclick = function() {
    drawButton.disabled = true;

    drawLineOverMap(map)
      .then(function(coordinates) {
        // Переводим координаты из 0..1 в географические.
        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        coordinates = coordinates.map(function(x) {
          return [
            // Широта (latitude).
            // Y переворачивается, т.к. на canvas'е он направлен вниз.
            bounds[0][0] + (1 - x[1]) * (bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]),
            // Долгота (longitude).
            bounds[0][1] + x[0] * (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]),
          ];
        });

        // Тут надо симплифицировать линию.
        // Для простоты я оставляю только каждую третью координату.
        coordinates = coordinates.filter(function (_, index) {
          return index % 3 === 0;
        });

        // Удаляем старый полигон.
        if (polygon) {
          map.geoObjects.remove(polygon);
        }

        // Создаем новый полигон
        polygon = new ymaps.Polygon([coordinates], {}, polygonOptions);
        map.geoObjects.add(polygon);

        drawButton.disabled = false;
      });
  };
});

function drawLineOverMap(map) {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('#draw-canvas');
  var ctx2d = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var drawing = false;
  var coordinates = [];

  // Задаем размеры канвасу как у карты.
  var rect = map.container.getParentElement().getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
  canvas.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
  canvas.width = rect.width;
  canvas.height = rect.height;

  // Применяем стили.
  ctx2d.strokeStyle = canvasOptions.strokeStyle;
  ctx2d.lineWidth = canvasOptions.lineWidth;
  canvas.style.opacity = canvasOptions.opacity;

  ctx2d.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Показываем канвас. Он будет сверху карты из-за position: absolute.
  canvas.style.display = 'block';

  canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    // При нажатии мыши запоминаем, что мы начали рисовать и координаты.
    drawing = true;
    coordinates.push([e.offsetX, e.offsetY]);
  };

  canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // При движении мыши запоминаем координаты и рисуем линию.
    if (drawing) {
      var last = coordinates[coordinates.length - 1];
      ctx2d.beginPath();
      ctx2d.moveTo(last[0], last[1]);
      ctx2d.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
      ctx2d.stroke();

      coordinates.push([e.offsetX, e.offsetY]);
    }
  };

  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    // При отпускании мыши запоминаем координаты и скрываем канвас.
    canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
      coordinates.push([e.offsetX, e.offsetY]);
      canvas.style.display = 'none';
      drawing = false;

      coordinates = coordinates.map(function(x) {
        return [x[0] / canvas.width, x[1] / canvas.height];
      });

      resolve(coordinates);
    };
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<button id="draw">рисовать</button>
<div id="container" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
  <canvas id="draw-canvas" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; display: none;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: flapenguin, спасибо огромное! Не могу оценить решение, так как рейтинг мал, но решение шикарное!)))) Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Наталья, пожалуйста. Вы можете отметить ответ как верный нажав на галочку слева (под стрелочками голосования).

Comment: вопрос решён !))) Скажите, пожалуйста, а есть ли в картах гугл подобный функционал?

Comment: @Наталья, вы можете точно так же положить поверх карты `<canvas>`, а а затем собрать из точек полигон.

Answer (score 0):

Для преобразования координаты у Яндекса есть специальный конвертер:

```
projection.fromGlobalPixels(
    map.converter.pageToGlobal([e.pageX, e.pageY]), map.getZoom()
)
```

```js
var polygonOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#0000ff',
  fillColor: '#8080ff',
  interactivityModel: 'default#transparent',
  strokeWidth: 4,
  opacity: 0.7
};

var canvasOptions = {
  strokeStyle: '#0000ff',
  lineWidth: 4,
  opacity: 0.7
};

ymaps.ready(['Map', 'Polygon']).then(function() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', { center: [55.75, 37.62], zoom: 8 });
  var polygon = null;

  var drawButton = document.querySelector('#draw');

  drawButton.onclick = function() {
    drawButton.disabled = true;

    drawLineOverMap(map)
      .then(function(coordinates) {
        // Тут надо симплифицировать линию.
        // Для простоты я оставляю только каждую третью координату.
        coordinates = coordinates.filter(function (_, index) {
          return index % 3 === 0;
        });

        // Удаляем старый полигон.
        if (polygon) {
          map.geoObjects.remove(polygon);
        }

        // Создаем новый полигон
        polygon = new ymaps.Polygon([coordinates], {}, polygonOptions);
        map.geoObjects.add(polygon);

        drawButton.disabled = false;
      });
  };
});

function drawLineOverMap(map) {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('#draw-canvas');
  var ctx2d = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var drawing = false;
  var coordinates = [];
    var offsets = [];

    // Задаем размеры канвасу как у карты.
    var rect = map.container.getParentElement().getBoundingClientRect();
    canvas.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
    canvas.width = rect.width;
    canvas.height = rect.height;

    // Применяем стили.
    ctx2d.strokeStyle = canvasOptions.strokeStyle;
    ctx2d.lineWidth = canvasOptions.lineWidth;
    canvas.style.opacity = canvasOptions.opacity;

    ctx2d.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Показываем канвас. Он будет сверху карты из-за position: absolute.
    canvas.style.display = 'block';

    canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
        // При нажатии мыши запоминаем, что мы начали рисовать и координаты.
        drawing = true;
        coordinates.push([e.pageX, e.pageY]);
        offsets.push([e.offsetX, e.offsetY]);
    };

    canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
        // При движении мыши запоминаем координаты и рисуем линию.
        if (drawing) {
            var last = offsets[offsets.length - 1];
            ctx2d.beginPath();
            ctx2d.moveTo(last[0], last[1]);
            ctx2d.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
            ctx2d.stroke();

            coordinates.push([e.pageX, e.pageY]);
            offsets.push([e.offsetX, e.offsetY]);
        }
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // При отпускании мыши запоминаем координаты и скрываем канвас.
        canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {

            coordinates.push([e.pageX, e.pageY]);
            canvas.style.display = 'none';
            drawing = false;

            var projection = map.options.get('projection');
            coordinates = coordinates.map(function(x) {
                return projection.fromGlobalPixels(
                    map.converter.pageToGlobal([x[0], x[1]]), map.getZoom()
                );
            });

            resolve(coordinates);
        };
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<button id="draw">рисовать</button>
<div id="container" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
  <canvas id="draw-canvas" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; display: none;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от критики других ответов в тексте вашего ответа. Когда у вас будет достаточно репутации, то вы сможете написать комментарий автору другого ответа с указанием недостатков.