# Как нарисовать на карте произвольную фигуру?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Мне необходимо реализовать функционал как на яндекс-недвижимость.
В песочнице примеров не нашел. Документацию тоже.
Где я могу узнать об этом функционале подробнее?

https://realty.yandex.ru/perm/kupit/kvartira/karta/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы о нанесении произвольных фигур на вашу карту? Вот пример в песочнице https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon

Comment: Нет, я именно о рисовании

Comment: Подозреваю, что вам нужен этот вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769738/Есть-ли-в-yandex-картах-рисование-произвольного-контура-и-сглаживание-контура-по/769884#769884

Comment: Да, самое то! это единственный вариант решения этой задачи! спасибо