# Как на яндекс картах нарисовать произвольную фигуру

Tags: swift, yandex-maps-api

Мне нужно на яндекс карте пальцем нарисовать произвольную фигуру, затем отобразить на карте список (метки) к примеру аптек которые есть внутри этой нарисованной фигуры.

Доку практически всю изучил, ответ так и не нашел. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Я бы сделал так - сверху карт сделал слой (view), который бы принимал жесты, эти жесты бы переводил в рисунок, по размеру и положению рисунка вычислял координаты на карте и показывал аптеки.

Comment: Я тоже именно так и подумал изначально, но мне не понятно как рисунок переводить в координаты?

Comment: Карта на экране имеет определенный масштаб в определенных координатах, соответственно, можно соотнести границы рисунка с координатами

Comment: Посмотрите пример в [аналогичном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769738/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-yandex-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be/769884#769884).

Answer (score 1):

Вот проект где можно рисовать произвольную область на карте https://h21-map-not-authorization.stackblitz.io/, также y yandex есть встроенная функция расчета видимой области или просто использовать код Javascript как вычислить вхождение точек в полигон

```
BelongingPolygon: function (coord, xp, yp) {
        var x = coord.Latitude;
        var y = coord.Longitude;

        npol = xp.length;
        j = npol - 1;
        var c = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < npol; i++) {
            if ((((yp[i] <= y) && (y < yp[j])) || ((yp[j] <= y) && (y < yp[i]))) &&
            (x > (xp[j] - xp[i]) * (y - yp[i]) / (yp[j] - yp[i]) + xp[i])) {
                c = !c
            }
            j = i;
        }
        return c;
    },
```